# Why doesn't setPrecision automatically use the least available precision?

Tags: c++

I have a text file which contains some values in each of the line like:

```
xxx.xxxxxx
```

I am reading each of the line and converting them to str using strod() and storing them in a temporary double variable.

when I print the value of that double variable, it outputs more digits than there should be after point.

The expected output should be:

```
xxx.xxxxxx
```

but I am getting

```
xxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

using setprecision(20). Any idea why is this happening?. Also how can I read what's exactly in the file?

Comment: Consider using a more descriptive title. =)

Comment: Please provide a minimum working example (including your input file) to allow others to reproduce the observed behavior. Otherwise there is no point in asking such question here.

Comment: Your "expected output" is less than your precision! If you're using `setprecision(20)`, getting 20 digits shouldn't be surprising! Isn't that what you're asking for? If it's there, for instance PI in its natural form never terminates or repeats, it will show to its limit. Therefore, in a PI example, you could use any `setprecsion` you like it will be 3.(xNumberOfPrecisionPointsLeft).

Comment: Also read: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: What actually I am interested in is getting a fixed length digits(such as six) after the point and to work with it. when I am keeping the value in a double variable it has very big precision implicity. I need to approximate it upto 4 digits after point and compare those to certain other values of this type. Does setprecision helps in approximate a value,rather printing it only??

Comment: Well, you might want to read them as a string and do some editing to it prior to any conversions. If each number read has a potential difference in precision that would be A WAY. Find the position in the string where the `.` resides and use it to grab x precision points there after. A side note to rounding and comparing though...rounding should be your last step in comparing or formulating, especially with important precision.

Comment: I wonder if what you really need isn't a `BigDecimal` class, which can represent decimal values exactly.  (It's not normally necessary except for legal reasons, but who knows.)

Answer (score 4):

If you ask for 20 digits precision in output, you're going to get it.
You seem to be surprised that you're getting something you explicitly
requested.  Anything other than 20 digits precision would surprise me.

As for what you read, typically, a number with 6 decimal places has no
exact representation in double; `strtod()` will return the closest
approximation.

I would suggest not trying to use `double` until you've read and
understood
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html.
`double` is *not* a real number.

Comment: Why put your answer as a comment in the first place?

Comment: @RobertoWilko As a preamble, yes:-).  The important points, I think are that numbers with six decimal digits don't have an exact representation, and that if you're going to use `double`, you'd best first learn what it is (which is what the document I link to explains).

Comment: You got my +1 in your bag buddy!

Answer (score 2):

You are reading what's in that file, but you can't store the *exact* number. Not every number can be precisely represented as a `double` (or anything else for that matter). Therefore, you'll get an approximation.